# Comparison of 2 different excel files using python

Tags: python

I have 2 different excel files with different number of rows and columns. I have to compare the amounts in both the excel sheets based on the unique ids and if there is any change in the value then I have to fetch those results and write the rows in a new excel file.Also If there is any new entry in 2nd excel then also need to copy the data into new excel. number of rows are different in both the files. I tried following approach but its not working and returning TypeError: 'Book' object is not subscriptable for the and condition in the if statement and if I am only iterating the rows without checking the same indexes then it is returning rows missing in the results

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import xlrd

rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('./first_file1.xlsx')
rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('./other_file1.xlsx')


sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = rb2``.sheet_by_index(0)

for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
    if (rownum < sheet2.nrows) and (rb1[0] == rb2[0]):
       row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
       row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)

for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
    if c1 != c2:
    print ("Cell {}{}  {} != {}".format(rownum+1, xlrd.formula.colname(colnum), c1, c2))
    else:
         print ("Row {} missing".format(rownum+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook('./first_file1.xlsx')
rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('./other_file1.xlsx')

sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)

new_df = []

for i, rownum_sheet2 in enumerate(range(sheet2.nrows)): #go through the (possible longer) sheet2
    row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum_sheet2)
    for rownum_sheet1 in range(sheet1.nrows): #go through sheet1 and check for same id
        row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum_sheet1)
        if row_rb1[0] == row_rb2[0]: #if the row with the same id is not equal: append to new df
            if row_rb1 != row_rb2:
                new_df.append(row_rb2)
    if i >= sheet1.nrows: #if there are extra rows, append to new df
        new_df.append(row_rb2)

#write new df to new excel-file
```

New Code:

```
df1_1 = pd.read_table('.../first_file.txt', sep = '/t')
df1_1.to_excel('filename1.xlsx') 
df_first_file = pd.concat([df1_1['Column'].str.split('  ',expand=True)],axis=1)
df_new1 = df_first_file.to_excel('first_file1.xlsx')


df1 = pd.read_table('.../otherfile.txt', sep = '/t')
df1.to_excel('filename2.xlsx') 
df_otherfile = pd.concat([df1['Column'].str.split('  ',expand=True)],axis=1)
df_new2 = df_otherfile.to_excel('other_file1.xlsx')

new_df = []

for i, rownum_sheet2 in enumerate(range(df_new2.nrows)): #go through the (possible longer) sheet2
    row_rb2 = df_new2.row_values(rownum_sheet2)
    for rownum_sheet1 in range(df_new1.nrows): #go through sheet1 and check for same id
        row_rb1 = df_new1.row_values(rownum_sheet1)
        if row_rb1[0] == row_rb2[0]: #if the row with the same id is not equal: append to new df
            if row_rb1 != row_rb2:
                new_df.append(row_rb2)
    if i >= df_new1.nrows: #if there are extra rows, append to new df
        new_df2 = new_df.append(row_rb2)
print (new_df2)
new_df.to_excel('final_filename.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried using this approach however it is not iterating over the excel sheet  and returning:   <xlrd.sheet.Sheet object at 0x0000022959284B08>
None

Comment: Since you made it to a excel-sheet you need to specify what data you want to have from that object (--> the sheets). Therefore you need to implement df_new1 = df_new1 .sheet_by_index(0) and df_new2 = df_new2 .sheet_by_index(0) again.